# How to pull-to-refresh webview in flutter? With refreshindicator

Tags: flutter, webview, refresh, pull-to-refresh

I try to use `refreshindicator` it need `listview`. When i wrapped webview into the `Container` or `SizedBox` the screen is not scrollable. Then i add `gestureRecognizers` and make it scrollable again then it cannot refresh again. Here is my code part.

```
.
.
.
child: RefreshIndicator(
                    // ignore: missing_return
                    onRefresh: () {
                      Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) =>
                                MyHomePage()), //when  refresh re render homepage widget
                      );
                    },
                    child: ListView(
                      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Stack(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            (Container(
                              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                              child: WebView(
                                gestureRecognizers: { //with this agin scrollable but not reload/refresh
                                  (Factory<VerticalDragGestureRecognizer>(
                                    () => VerticalDragGestureRecognizer() ..onUpdate = (_) {} )),
                                },
                                onWebResourceError:
                                    (WebResourceError webviewer) {
                                  setState(() {
                                    internet = false;
                                  });
                                  print("No Connection solve it");
                                },
                                initialUrl: "www.google.com",
                                javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
.
.
.
                                ),
                            ),
                            ),
                            ]),
                        ),
                        ),
                        ),
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to reload webview in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57215843/how-to-reload-webview-in-flutter)

Comment: No. This work with flat button or smthing button. I wanna use pull-to-refresh. Thx for your time.

Comment: @Z_Z have you got any solution on it ?

Comment: Yes, Actually no need at all because the new version of connectivity has event listener. I mean this listen connectivity activities. Directly refreshed :=)

Comment: How did you solve this with connectivity? Will you please share your code?