# How to add a refresh indicator to a webview in flutter?

Tags: flutter, listview, dart, webview

I am using the official webview package in my app in order to display a webview but the problem is that I can't use the refresh indicator widget and I looked up for many solutions even issues opened on github and I got no results

I will be really thankful If someone told me how can I add a scrollable widget above the webview widget without affecting the webview scrolling.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Do you mean to say that you want pull-to-refresh in webview?

Comment: yes I mean that

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57215843/how-to-reload-webview-in-flutter

you can try this example i also check this and this is working fine at my end

Comment: it is working but what I want is doing this function by refresh indicator

Answer (score 1):

The below codes will help you to show RefreshIndicator in the above of Webview. If the following codes match your use case, you can use them. ;)

```
    return RefreshIndicator(
      onRefresh: () async => Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3)),
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        child: Container(
          height: viewHeight, // MediaQuery.of(context).size.height.
          width: viewWidth, // MediaQuery.of(context).size.width.
          child: WebView(
            initialUrl: 'https://www.google.co.in/?gws_rd=ssl',
            javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
            onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
              _controller.complete(webViewController);
            },
            javascriptChannels: <JavascriptChannel>[
              _toasterJavascriptChannel(context),
            ].toSet(),
            navigationDelegate: (NavigationRequest request) {
              if (request.url.startsWith('https://www.youtube.com/')) {
                print('blocking navigation to $request}');
                return NavigationDecision.prevent;
              }
              print('allowing navigation to $request');
              return NavigationDecision.navigate;
            },
            onPageStarted: (String url) {
              print('Page started loading: $url');
            },
            onPageFinished: (String url) {
              print('Page finished loading: $url');
            },
            gestureNavigationEnabled: true,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Comment: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height will not give the hight of webview.

Comment: Tried and webview with greater height than container won't scroll. We need something that set either container to height of webview's page or set container to fill available space and let webview itself scroll.